# Новая метка [чистая-архитектура]?

Tags: предложение, добавление-меток

Недавно начал изучать clean-architecture. Интересно почему здесь нет такой метки? Думали над добавлением?

Comment: А на русский перевести?

Comment: Создание меток доступно для участников с репутацией от 300 и выше. Если хотите создать метку - просто создайте, не нужно ради этого создавать обсуждение на мете :)

Comment: @PashaPash, ну мало ли, с сообществом то нужно посоветоваться. Потом будут появляться обсуждения об их удалении :)

Comment: Если новая метка будет в тему, то никто ее не тронет - именно так метки и рождаются.

Comment: У нас людей-то нет столько интересующихся этой темой, так что метка такая не особо нужна. Но если создадите - вряд ли кто тронет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая [привилегия, как "создавать новые метки"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) — требуется всего 300 репутации, можно сразу при создании вопроса указывать текст новой метки и она создастся при сохранении вопроса.

Этой привилегией достаточно активно пользуются и тем на мете создавать не принято. Я например создавал метки типа [centos7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/centos7) и [laravel5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel5).

Так что если вы чувствуете, что вам текущих меток не хватает для того, чтобы классифицировать вопрос — создавайте, препятствий нет.

Если захотите сделать это грамотно — сразу предложите и краткое/подробное описание метки, чтобы было понятно в каких случаях её использовать.

Далее — моё личное мнение о необходимости данной метки.

Я не вижу какой-то большой потребности в создании такой метки. 
Всё, что вы хотите сказать по вопросу "чистой архитектуры" вполне точно описывается меткой "архитектура". 
У нас нет аншлага по метке архитектура: за всё время набралось всего 400 вопросов плюс по 10 вопросов в месяц добавляется новых. Был бы большой вал вопросов - можно было бы детальнее классифицировать, а так...

Также в помощь связанные метки. Есть работающий код — можно добавить [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0). Также можно использовать более конкретные разделы чистой архитектуры, например: [ооп](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%be%d0%bf), [mvc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc), [паттерны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b), [ddd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ddd), [dependency-injection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dependency-injection), [inversion-of-control](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inversion-of-control), [refactoring](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refactoring).

То есть я не вижу разницы между метками вопроса архитектура + dependency-injection и чистая-архитектура + dependency-injection.

По-моему вполне пока достаточно, не?

Comment: убедили. не буду создавать